# `dir=auto` breaks in latest Chrome (90)

Tags: html, google-chrome

This used to work in Chrome but Chrome 90 breaks `dir='auto'` and doesn't correctly detect the language direction.

You can verify by running the snippet below in Chrome 90 versus all other browsers.

Other than manually determining and setting `dir='rtl'` are there any browser hacks or global workarounds to make this work with `dir='auto'`?

```html
<p dir="auto">English</p>
<p dir="auto">اُردُو‎,</p>
<p dir="ltr">اُردُو‎,</p>
<p dir="rtl">اُردُو‎,</p>
```